# How to open a File Menu and then, click on one of its sub menu after opening that external .exe file in Python?

Tags: python, windows, image-processing, textures, mouse

What I have is Image Texture Analysis software - Mazda as .exe file. I need to open this file, Click on the menu 'File' and then the sub menu 'Load Macro', all in Python.
Searching on the internet, yielded me results to use mouse hovering techniques.
Is there any direct way with the help of which we could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) or [swapy](https://code.google.com/p/swapy/). Both of these packages are for Windows Automation.

Comment: I tried using these both, but the problem is, both of these packages treat the various static components as single sub window with single reference variable. Like for eg. in Ms paint (there are various components available at the top of the window such as tools, shapes) ,the swapy gives the reference of the entire component panel, but not as how to refer to a particular component within that panel. Is there any way with the help of which we can achieve this?